# Am I able to perform number-based operations without auto-incremented numeric columns?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, sql-order-by, primary-key

Assume that in a database table, I decide to use some sort of string as a primary key, given the fact that in cases, this can be unique enough for each record. (Imgur pictures, Youtube videos, Reddit posts, maybe even Stack Overflow question, and so on)

In this case, however, I would rather avoid the use of an auto-incremented numeric field.

Does it prevent me to make actions like:

- select the first 200 rows of the table?
- select 30 rows of the table, where a certain column's content equals to a given value?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Without `ORDER BY` the `LIMIT` clause is free to pick random rows.

It's easy enough to select a limited number of table rows...

```
  SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE condition LIMIT 200
```

The problem you face is this: SQL doesn't have any inbuilt concept of order for rows.   This query will give you 200 rows from the table, but the actual rows it gives are formally speaking, *unpredictable.*

It happens that most SQL implementations (MySQL and other servers) give the same 200 rows if you issue the same query, but this is not guaranteed. If you rely on this same-rows behavior you can get nasty problems when the server decides to change which rows it gives you. This can happen around a version upgrade. It can also happen if your tables grow and the server's query planner comes up with a new way of retrieving a subset of a larger set.

So, if you want to, as you wrote, "select the first 200 rows of the table" in a predictable fashion, you need to have some way of defining the order.  An autoincrementing id is one way to do that, but you have ruled that out. Maybe you have an `insert_date` column, and "first" means "oldest."  You could do

```
  SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE condition ORDER BY insert_date LIMIT 200
```

Comment: If experience shows that it is preferred and has less issues than advantages, then I'd add an autoincremented id column, I just avoid it if its's unnecessary.

Comment: An auto `id` column is a good way to get a primary key and ordering.  It also comes in handy (performance-wise) if you need to JOIN this table to others. Unless there's a good reason, in the real-world data you are representing, to omit an `id` column it's good to include it.